# rsync copied the first module but not the other modules : rsync: change_dir "/volume2" (in volume1) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: rsync

I have the following rsyncd.conf :

```bash
$ egrep -v "^$|^#" /etc/rsyncd.conf
log file = /var/log/rsyncd.log
pid file = /var/run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /var/run/rsync.lock
use chroot = no
read only = yes
dont compress = aac *.aiff *.aif *.avi *.m2ts *.m4v *.mov *.MOV *.mp4 *.mpg *.mxf *.tif *.wav *.png *.zip
exclude = .DS_Store desktop.ini \#recycle/
[volume1]
path = /volume1
[volume2]
path = /volume2
[volume3]
path = /volume3
```

And here is what `rsync`says :

```bash
$ syncCommand="rsync --stats -Hauv -h -P"
$ $syncCommand --log-file=$HOME/log/synchro_detailed_ADN_$(date +%Y%m%d).log "rsync://SOURCE-SERVER:/volume1/Archive 04" "rsync://SOURCE-SERVER:/volume2/Archive 05" "rsync://SOURCE-SERVER:/volume3/Archive 06" /ring/0/share/Archives_ADN/ 2>&1 | tee ~/log/synchro_ADN_$(date +%Y%m%d).log
receiving incremental file list
rsync: change_dir "/volume2" (in volume1) failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/volume3" (in volume1) failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: failed to set times on "/ring/0/share/Archives_ADN/Archive 04": Operation not permitted (1)
Archive 04/

Number of files: 6,473 (reg: 6,235, dir: 238)
Number of created files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 0
Total file size: 16.63T bytes
Total transferred file size: 0 bytes
Literal data: 0 bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 190.81K
File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 270
Total bytes received: 208.94K

sent 270 bytes  received 208.94K bytes  4.70K bytes/sec
total size is 16.63T  speedup is 79,476,844.88
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1651) [generator=3.1.2]
```

EDIT0 : It seems `rsync` can only copy one module at a time : https://github.com/WayneD/rsync/issues/367#issuecomment-1232434700

Why did `rsync` copied only the first module (`volume1`) but not the other modules ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you can only copy from one module per rsync command. This seems a fair restriction, as different modules may need different authentication and basically requires the protocol to restart completely.
There seems to be no explicit mention of this in the `rsync` and `rsyncd.conf` man pages. The only example of 2 sources uses the same module twice, which works well:

```
rsync -av host::modname/file{1,2} host::modname/file3 /dest/
```

Comment: All of the modules I'm copying from are from the same server therefore using the same authentication. Why would there be a protocol restart ?

Comment: In general, each module can specify a different list of `auth users`, and `secrets file` and `host allow` and so on, so rsyncd would have to potentially validate a new user and password etcetera for each change in module.